# Unity c#: transform.forward using global forward instead of local

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, global

I am making an AI spider which will stop when it gets too close to a wall. However, using my code below it only succeeds in executing Idle() when facing the northern wall of the maze (Global forward).

I am using Unity3D 4.6.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spider : MonoBehaviour {

    public float movementSpeed, rotationSpeed;

    //Called by game manager after instantiation
    public void SetLocation (MazeCell cell) {
        transform.localPosition = 
            new Vector3(
                cell.transform.localPosition.x,
                5f,
                cell.transform.localPosition.z
                );
        float startingRotation = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(-0.5f,3.49999f));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,startingRotation * 90,0);
    }   

    void Update() {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 0.5f)) {
            if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, 2)) {
                Walk();
            } else {
                Idle ();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Idle() {
        animation.Play("idle");
    }

    private void Walk() {
        transform.Translate(transform.forward * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        animation.Play("walk");
    }

    }
```

*Edit:*

`Debug.Log()` calls
[image: Debug. Log () calls]

New Code
[image: New Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question (but I have to give credit to @matther-spencer for helping me see these possibilities and reliably assisting me). The problem was, in fact, a collection of problems.

The most significant problem was that the origin of the raycast was low. This was including the floors as walls to stop for, hence making the spider fail to walk. This also prevented the downwards `Raycast` from working.

However, a combination of `transform.forward` and `Vector3.forward` were eventually necessary to get the desired functionality. Here is the final code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spider : MonoBehaviour {

public float movementSpeed, rotationSpeed;

public void SetLocation (MazeCell cell) {
    transform.localPosition = 
        new Vector3(
            cell.transform.localPosition.x,
            5f,
            cell.transform.localPosition.z
            );
    float startingRotation = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(-0.5f,3.49999f));
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,startingRotation * 90,0);
}   

void Update() {
    Debug.Log ("updating");
    if (Physics.Raycast(
        new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.25f, transform.position.z),
        Vector3.down,
        0.5f)) {
        Debug.Log("downraycheck passed");
        if (!Physics.Raycast(
            new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.25f, transform.position.z),
            transform.forward,
            2)) {
            Debug.Log("forwardraycheck passed");
            Walk();
        } else {
            Debug.Log("forwardraycheck failed");
            Idle ();
        }
    }
}

private void Idle() {
    Debug.Log("idling");
    animation.Play("idle");
}

private void Walk() {
    Debug.Log("walking");
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    animation.Play("walk");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it look like the Spider's forward is facing the right direction?  If the spider is too close to the wall, it would be expected to be idle as !Physics.Raycast would be false.  Perhaps you will need to debug these and confirm that they are coming up as expected.

I am doing some presuming here, but it appears that the Spider object is instantiated with a y of 5.0f, then in the Update call, you are doing a RayCast in the Down direction.  If there are no colliders in the down direction for half a unit, then nothing will happen.  Of course, if there is gravity and a colliding floor, this would likely work fine.

Comment: Gravity and a floor do apply. When the spider spawns, the forward arrow is in the correct direction. As it turns, the forward arrow remains in the same (north) direction, but I can't say I've seen it move in the past when working with other rotating objects.

Comment: It appears that the rotation is only being applied upon instantiation, and at no other point in the code (Update, Idle or Walk), so I can't see where the rotations are occurring.

Comment: Yes, no rotations other than the one on instantiation should be occurring for now. The current intended functionality is to spawn facing a random direction (0,90, 180, 270) then walk until getting close to a wall at which point its animation will change to "idle" and it will stop moving.  However I have rotated it (by a multiple of 90 degrees) in the editor once or twice.

Comment: Best I can think of at this time is that there is no floor underneath, the northern wall is not a collider, the rotation is not correctly assigned or the code doesn't trigger.  Does the Walk and Idle Code operate?  Have you placed debug code to confirm the state of the game?  Sorry, but it's hard to diagnose without further details.

Comment: The walk and Idle functions both trigger and function correctly. The northern wall is the only one that works correctly. There is definitely a working floor (the first raycast allows the if statement to continue on every frame).

Comment: Can you supply a basic project that replicates the issue and I'll have a look, thx

Comment: I'll just send you the project if you want :)

Comment: Hmm @matthew-spencer I was playing around with this today and i added in some debug lines. I notice the if statements only run twice whereas the frame updates every time. Please see the pictures in the edited question.